# Magnolia CMS on IIS

Tags: iis-6, tomcat5.5

I have a webserver running windows 2003 with a bunch of ASP.net Websites currently listening on port 80 (with different host headers).

I need to setup a TomCat instance to handle a Magnolia CMS installation that will also need to listen on port 80 with a host header like:

`magnolia.cms.somedomain.com`.

I've done some google searches and all I could find was [this blog post on how to setup neosmart](http://neosmart.net/blog/2006/configuring-jsp-for-iis/) which isn't working.

***Update:** 
I'm not trying to get Tomcat and IIS to listen on port 80, instead I want IIS to delegate to TomCat when a request comes in for a particular website. I've heard that this can be done, the link above even gives directions on how to achieve this but those directions aren't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your request correctly, you want to have 1 server with 1 ip address have 2 webserver processes each use port 80 for HTTP traffic, redirecting requests to different virtual web sites by means of their host headers.

In my view this cannot be done, because the processes (iis6 and tomcat) will each try to set up their services on TCP port 80, and the last service to start will fail.

However, Windows Servers can easily be configured with more than one IP address assigned to a single NIC, and this is the way you can make this work.

This way if you set up IIS listening on one IP, and Tomcat on the other, you can have as many virtual web sites on each IP address as you'd like.

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear on the ports part. I'm not trying to get IIS and tomcat to listen on 80 but rather have IIS delegate requests to Tomcat for a particular website.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting this to work but I had to re-install Tomcat fresh and re-configure the mod_jk ISAPI plugin exactly as it's specified [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html).

I accepted tptechs answer because if I followed those directions I would have been done in about 1/2 the time :D